# Changing date in drop down list to yyyy/mm/dd in c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I currently have a Drop down list that has been bound with dates from a database. The dates differ depending on which username is selected in a different drop down list. I am trying to populate a GridView depending on these values and when the selected index changes on the dates drop down list.

However the dates being displayed in my drop down list are dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00, which means that I can't use them to display data from the database based on the values. As my Date in the database are stored as yyyy/mm/dd. As I am getting the error : 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Any idea on how to change the format in the drop down list?

I understand that this might be used: DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); however I can't work out where.

C# for binding data to my second drop down list:

```
private void BindDropDownList2(String field)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            String Query = "Select StockDate from Stock_Take WHERE Username = @Value1";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", field);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlDa.Fill(dataTable);
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList2.DataSource = dataTable;
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "StockDate";
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "StockDate";

                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Fetch Error";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: so, in your drop down list, you want the dates to be formatted as `yyyy/mm/dd` ? is that all ?

Comment: @zackraiyan yes as opposed to dd/mm/yyyy ss/mm/hh

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , a `DataTable` is unnecessary here.Go with a `IDataReader` , it's a better option.The reason is simple.A `DataTable` uses a `DataAdapter` and stores data from the database.Which means you have 2 datatables,one in the database(original one) and one in the code behind.If you go with `IDataReader` it means that you are reading the data-table from the database itself and not storing it again in code-behind.

Ow, did i forget to tell that a `DataReader` is proven to be faster than a `DataAdapter` ? :).

I'l glad that you almost answered you own question with this line :

> I understand that this might be used: DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

All you have to do is put it all together :

```
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", field);
  SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

  While (dr.Read())
   {
     DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString("yyyy MMM ddd"), ""));
   }  //I didn't debug this line but it should work :)
```

**Update**

As OP said that the data-type of the given column is `VarChar`, then `.ToString()` will do it :)

```
   DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString()),"");
```

Comment: When asserting something is better, it's often useful to justify ***why*** it's better ;)

Comment: @zackraiyan Thanks for the help!! There is an error of the 'ToString'. Saying "no overload for method tostring takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @fredbrass , gimme a minute to check

Comment: How about a link to the "proven to be faster". Since a DataTable is an in memory representation of data in a database and a DataReader is a firehose - forward only read only. I don't think they can be compared for speed.

Comment: Take a look at the answers [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9104d3e-0736-433c-b403-39a33ac76d2d/datareader-vs-datatable?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) @Mary

Comment: @zackraiyan I am shocked! I thought you said (previously) that '.AddWithValue' would corrupt data.

Comment: @Mary , `AddWithValue` conflicts with data when the format is `DateTime` or similar and only when you are inserting data into the db , not when fetching from it......

Comment: @zackraiyan Okay, I had a small error in other parts of the code which i changed, now it's giving a similar but more precise error " The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Comment: wait what !! ?? u said the column's data-type was date time right ? however i will add a workaround

Comment: and hey, if it is varchar , just use `ToString()` , no formatting needed lol

Comment: @zackraiyan You can load a DataTable with a DataReader. Then which is faster? You simply bind to DataTable.   Of course this is ASP.

Comment: @Mary,what is your question basically ? A datareader returns you the value when it is reading the table but a `DataTaeble` stores the values first and then return 'em...i guess you fail to see the obvious

Comment: You can compare DataAdapter.Fill and DataReader but not DataTable and DataReader.

Comment: ow....really ? umm... i thought i mentioned `The reason is simple.A DataTable uses a DataAdapter` in my answer , amybe i forgot to mention that , didn't i ?

Comment: @zackraiyan is the code you've given to replace the If statement in my original code?

Comment: @fredbrass , yes, it will replace your if statement totally and also the `DataTable` and `DataAdapter`

Comment: @zackraiyan You can load a DataTable with a DataReader; no DataAdapter involved.

Comment: @Mary , what is the issue you are having with my answer exactly ?

Comment: Stop begging! My issues is the DataTable being slower. The DataTable doesn't have a speed.

Comment: @Mary , who said i am begging huh ? You kept on asking the same question again and again...My answer makes it obvious that the OP's current method is not too performance friendly......And i did mention that it was `IDataAdapter` what `IDataReader` uses....No one's having a problem except for you ... So,shouldn't i say `Stop begging` to you ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I've had to revert back to my old data adapter code, because the binding stopped working as the values in the drop down list 2 were not affected by the value selected in the drop down list two. How can i adapt the DropDownList2.Items.Add line to the original data adapter code?

Comment: @fredbrass , u need to loop through all the records in the datatable and add each item to the drop downlist